# What is the difference between O1 and Os?

Tags: c, gcc

May I know what is the difference between O1 and Os? I only the firmware size compiled by Os is smaller than O1. However, what is the different in performance wise? Would it has much different?

Comment: The benefit of the optimizations is going to depend largely on your code base, and only profiling builds on either setting is going to really give you a good answer. [Here's the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/gcc/) for reference though

Answer (score 1):

You can read about GCC's different optimization levels [in the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). In particular, `-O1`

> tries to reduce code size and execution time, without performing any optimizations that take a great deal of compilation time.

On the other hand, `-Os` means:

> Optimize for size. -Os enables all -O2 optimizations except those that often increase code size